# Blender render object scale different from viewport

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine, scale, depth-of-field

So I've been doing this animation in Blender, but when I hit render to check on the lighting, I found that one of the object changed. Here's the picture of the viewport:[image]

And here's the render result (EEVEE): [image]

As you can see, the road seems to change, I guess in scale because this happened to me before but in Cycles. I don't want to scale every object to match the road, is there any way I can fix this?

Oh and extra question, how do you make the city background (it's a plane) to blurry bokeh? I think it's not blurry enough. The camera aperture is already set at f 1.8 and the plane is really far from the camera, but so far it doesn't change anything.

Comment: Hello :). When geometry is changing only in renders, it's often some forgotten modifier...

Comment: First I would try to select the road and do Object > Apply > Scale. Also I would check the outliner for an object that might be in the location of the road and be Hidden in Viewport but that might not be set to Disable in Render. (Click on the Filter button/funnel Icon to toggle visibility of these states.)